# PHP/SQL After insert value to table and set one value as unique, no more values can be inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, insert

I try to create normalized db.

When I insert values FIRST time, everything is working perfectly, but (I think cause of set values as UNIQUE) it do not want to add.

This is my queries ( I can show database as well if needed )

```
$query = "INSERT INTO userMore (userEmailG, userGenderG, userAboutG, userBirthdayG, userLanguageG) values ('$userEmailG','$userGenderG', '$userAboutG', '$userBirthdayG', '$userLanguageG');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO userBasic (id_uM, userNameG, userEmailG) values ((SELECT id_uM FROM userMore WHERE userEmailG='$userEmailG'),'$userNameG', '$userEmailG');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO dvlaInfoMore (sixMonthRate, twelveMonthRate, wheelPlan, revenueWeight, typeApproval, taxStatus, taxed, taxDetails, mot, motDetails) values ('$sixMonthRate', '$twelveMonthRate', '$wheelPlan', '$revenueWeight', '$typeApproval', '$taxStatus', '$taxed', '$taxDetails', '$mot', '$motDetails');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO dvlaInfoBasic (id_uDInfoM, plateNumber, make, model, yearOfManufacture, cylinderCapacity, dateofFirstRegistration, co2Emissions, fuelType, colour, vin, transmission)
values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$plateNumber', '$make', '$model', '$yearOfManufacture', '$cylinderCapacity', '$dateofFirstRegistration', '$co2Emissions', '$fuelType', '$colour', '$vin', '$transmission');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO userLocation (latitude, longitude, postCode) values ('$latitude', '$longitude', '$postCode');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO userChioce (doWithCar) values ('$doWithCar');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO userStatus (userIdG) values ('$userIdG');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO userMain (userIdG, id_uB, id_uDInfoB, id_uChoice, id_uLoc, id_uStat) values ('$userIdG', (SELECT id_uB FROM userBasic WHERE userEmailG='$userEmailG'), (SELECT id_uDInfoB FROM dvlaInfoBasic WHERE plateNumber ='$plateNumber'), LAST_INSERT_ID(), (SELECT id_uLoc FROM userLocation WHERE postCode='$postCode'),(SELECT id_uStat FROM userStatus WHERE userIdG='$userIdG'))";
```

So, first time userMore added then userBasic then dvlaInfoMore then dvlaInfoBasic  and so one

I set in userBasic column userNameG as UNIQUE, so IF inserted email which already exist, it do not want to go further,  BUT if not, everything added correctly.

ALL what I want that it will continue inserting different cars and then by using existing email display result in table userMain.

**P.S.** if I try to add different car from by using same email address it doesn't work., basically do not add anything.

Comment: @JFOG Shouldn't `userEmailG` be UNIQUE (instead of `userNameG`) if you want to prevent duplicate email addresses? Currently, you are preventing duplicate names.

Comment: @Guido Currently unique is 'userEmailG', there is no issue with 'userBasic' and 'userMore' , main problem WHY it do not want to add different car and by using existing 'userBasic' display 'userBasic ID' with different 'dvlaInfoBasic' in 'userMain'

Comment: @Guido Problem is I can add first car information BUT i can add second car info, so second time I want to add something i will not change anything unless I use different email address and the it execute nicely. SO basically to execute perfectly every-time I suppose to have different email, how can I fix it?

Comment: One thing I just noticed: your `INSERT INTO userMain` inserts `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into column `id_uChoice`. However, at this stage the last insert ID is from the previous query `INSERT INTO userStatus`, not `userChoice`. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Guido do you have a time? I can show you my database  on screen and so on? Please, just sitting like an idiot already 5-7 hours, can't fix it.

Comment: I can't do that right now, but maybe you could build a simplified test database and example `INSERT` statements on http://sqlfiddle.com which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Guido do you have skype?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected yourself, `INSERT` with an existing key defined as UNIQUE will fail.

One workaround is to use the `REPLACE INTO` statement instead of `INSERT` (see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)).

Comment: I have tried, same as before, once I have insert everything, and the even with different value, nothing additional added.

Comment: By using REPLACE INTO, it do not insert anything at all.